# Why does my dimmer does not totally turn off the light?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I bought a 2 Ceiling Lights (Halo BLD606930WHR)  with 2 Dimmers (Lutron DVCL-153PR-WH). They are compatible lights and dimmers.

When turning the dimmer Totally down to 0%,  one of the lights continues to remain on at very dim level,  the other light shuts off completely like its supposed to.

Do you know what the issue can be, and how can it be fixed? Maybe something installation? Additionally, does having a light like this, cause any damage to the circuit, or a hazard?

The dimmers and switches seems to be work normal aside from that, when using it above 0%. Using the light switches will turn off both lights, which is good.

**Update**

The Halo lights are 8W Watts.

One thing I noticed in our house, this issue does Not Occur with other ceiling light brands of higher 18W or 15W installed on same dimmer type.  Wondering if higher wattage gets rid of the dimmer 'ghosting' issue.

[image]

[image]

**Resources:**

[https://www.amazon.com/Halo-BLD606930WHR-Integrated-Recessed-Compliant/dp/B07FRP2VYY](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FRP2VYY)

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Lutron-Single-Pole-or-3-Way-Diva-LED-Dimmer-Switch-for-Dimmable-LED-Halogen-and-Incandescent-Bulbs-White-DVCL-153PR-WH/203670402

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the instructions for the switch. It states it is designed for incandescent lamps. This technology runs a small amount of power through the load to function it is not visible with incandescent lamps but is with LED’s because they take a small fraction of the power to illuminate. So that small amount of current is the cause of the lamp not shutting completely off.

Comment: hi, actually it was a mistype on amazon, if reading closer, its actually for LED, as I saw on instructions  https://www.homedepot.com/p/Lutron-Single-Pole-or-3-Way-Diva-LED-Dimmer-Switch-for-Dimmable-LED-Halogen-and-Incandescent-Bulbs-White-DVCL-153PR-WH/203670402

Comment: "Provides best dimming performance for LED bulbs etc"

Comment: "The Diva LED+ dimmer provides optimal dimming performance of LED bulbs. This dimmer works with up to 150-Watt of dimmable LED/CFL or 600-Watt of incandescent/halogen, allowing you to control multiple bulb types on the same circuit. It is designed to control a broad range of dimmable LED and CFL bulbs from a variety of brands including Philips, Cree, GE, EcoSmart and Lighting Science. "

Comment: anyways, is this kind of behavior in LEDs and dimmers normal, nothing to worry about?

Comment: I just went to the linked document. If there are 2 blacks and a green a good ground is required as the switch returns the current on the ground to function so that may also be the problem but if I remember correctly without a ground they will not work. As far as if this is normal, yes it is a common occurrence when the switch draws power through the load it may be 2-3 watts and that is enough to make your LED’s glow.

Comment: I have a white and a black I know, well if the electrician whos certified doing 20 yrs can't do anything about it, I'll let it be, unless you have anymore suggestions, appreciate it

Comment: A white and black indicates a switch loop if there is no bare copper I don’t know of an electronic switch that will work,